# Too many open files Websocket

Tags: go, websocket

Process leaves too many opened file descriptor. 
When i do: lsof -p $pid, most of results are (about 80%):

> points2 28360 root  911u     sock                0,9      0t0 42082509
>   protocol: TCPv6

Before FD Type turns to 'sock', it stays as CLOSE_WAIT for a while. What I noticed is that some of these 'sock' FDs disapears, some stay forever

Amount of open files increases gradually with small fluctuations till it not reaches the maximum 1024. Currently i set allowed maximum amount of open files for 4096, to make process work longer.

```
srvTLS := &http.Server{
    Addr:         utils.PortSocketTLS,
    ReadTimeout:  10 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
}
srvTLS.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)
```

Handler:

```
func WsRoom(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
ws, err := websocket.Upgrade(w, r, nil, 1024, 1024)
if _, ok := err.(websocket.HandshakeError); ok {
    http.Error(w, "Not a websocket handshake", 400)
    return
} else if err != nil {
    return
}
...other stuff
}
```

Writer to conn

```
func PlayerWriter(pc *model.PlayerConn) {
ticker := time.NewTicker(utils.PingPeriod)
defer func() {
    ticker.Stop()
    pc.WS.Close()
}()
for {
    select {
    case message, ok := <-pc.Ch:
        pc.WS.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(utils.WriteWait))
        if !ok {
            pc.WS.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, []byte{})
            return
        }

        err := pc.WS.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        inst := &model.PlayerLeftInstruction{}
        _ = json.Unmarshal(message, inst)

        if inst.Instruction == utils.UtilAFK || inst.Instruction == utils.RoomMoneyLess {
            return
        }
        break
    case <-ticker.C:
        pc.WS.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(utils.WriteWait))
        if err := pc.WS.WriteMessage(websocket.PingMessage, nil); err != nil {
            return
        }
        break
    }
}}
```

Conn Listener:

```
func PlayerListener(pc *model.PlayerConn) {
defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
    }
    close(pc.Ch)
    pc.Room.Leave <- pc
    pc.WS.Close()
}()

pc.WS.SetReadLimit(utils.MaxMessageSize)
pc.WS.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(utils.PongWait))
pc.WS.SetPongHandler(func(string) error { pc.WS.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(utils.PongWait)); return nil })

for {
    _, command, err := pc.WS.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    si := model.StatusInstruction{}
    json.Unmarshal(command, &si)
    z := make([]byte, len(command))
    copy(z, command)
    switch si.Status {
    case utils.PlayerLeft:
        goto Exit
    case utils.MoveTurn, utils.LocalTurn, utils.LocalBetFold, utils.LocalBet, utils.MoveTurnBet:
        pc.Room.RoomData.GameBridger.InstCh <- z
        break
    ...some stuff
    default:
        log.Printf("Unexpected command is responsed it is: %s", string(command))
        goto Exit
    }
}
Exit:
}
```

If it's needed, i can share more code. I think problem with timeouts and something refered to this, but i don't exactly know where i'm missing

Comment: What websocket library are you using?

Comment: The application uses one file descriptor per connected client.  Do you have that many connected clients?  If not, then the application is leaking connections.  Add logging statements before the two calls to `pc.WS.Close()` to confirm that the application is closing connections.  It's possible that application is not closing connections because the goroutines are blocked.  Also, run the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) to check for data races.

Comment: @DeanElbaz Websocket this libriary:  https://github.com/gorilla/websocket

Answer (score 0):

In lsof, TYPE 'sock' usually means: socket connection that didn't recived anything.
I had logical error in my code by NOT closing in some cases the established websocket connection.
Also i had goroutine leaks (however it didn't affected on lsof number), pprof helped to detect leaks.